# Not able to map a view with url

Tags: django

I am facing some problem while mapping a view with URL

Project name-Hero
app name-Movie

Hero/url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^',include('Movie.urls'))
]
```

Movie/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='Movie'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello friends ,Welcome to Django Project</h1>")
```

These are my urls and views configurations.I am getting a 404 page.
Please help me out.. Thanks

Comment: Please mention which url you hits.

Comment: @Ravi Ranjan According to your code, the index view can be viewed in host address, that is **`localhost:8000`**

Comment: share the full url from your browser and error if any. The code overall looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code, only changes in Hero/url.py

Hero/url.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns=[
    url(r'^admin/',admin.site.urls),
    url(r'',include('Movie.urls'))   # Do not add caret sign if further urls contains caret.
]
```